Fluent Bit Compression Format and System Resource Usage
I'm working with Fluent Bit for log processing and have two questions regarding compression:
Compression Format: Does Fluent Bit compress logs into a specific format after compression (e.g., gzip)? Or does the original format (JSON, unstructured) remain within a compressed container? how compression works ?
System Resource Impact: While I understand compression reduces data size, does it significantly impact system resources during processing in Fluent Bit? Are there any factors influencing this impact (e.g., compression ratio, hardware specs)?
I've searched the documentation but haven't found a clear explanation on these specific aspects. Any insights or relevant documentation references would be appreciated.
